# FindBy Not autogenerated by Custom Tool

Tags: c#, xsd.exe, msdatasetgenerator

I have a Users table with the following column names: Username,Password,EmployeeID,                  UserType,PasswordExpires,PasswordValidUntil,SecurityQuestion,SecurityAnswer,ActiveUser

I have included the data source and dataset in the project. After running the Custom tool I cannot find the FindBy method in the datasetDesigner.cs for searching the data in the datatable by the Username.

Comment: Can you show us some code that should work?

Comment: public SystemUsersRow FindByUsername(string Username)
{
 return (SystemUsersRow)this.Rows.Find(new object[] { Username });
}

Comment: I cannot find this method in the auto generated method as I would like to search from the table Users. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, storing passwords is a very, VERY bad practice.

Comment: Username is not a Key. I have included EmployeeID as a foreign key